# how to clear input type="datetime" via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a problem trying to clear with javascript a form with an input of type="datetime"

because the following code doesen't work when i add input:datetime

```
$form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
```

Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why don't you use `.reset()`?

Comment: jQuery does not have `:datetime` pseudo class... see: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Reset() doesnt erase content of input, it just reverts inputs content to its initial state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `input[type=datetime]` selector instead.

```
$form.find('input[type=datetime]').val('');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMffk/)

Answer (score 3):

You would have to use this selector instead:

```
$('input[type="datetime"]').val('');
```

Since jQuery as of v1.10 does not recognize `input:datetime` as a valid selector.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wtevn3z/)